# CSS rotate to create diagonal borders

Tags: css, rotation, transform

http://www.rockybeachstudio.de/gz/

I'm trying to create a glass-effect by duplicating and slightly misaligning the content of the website. I'm using nested containers with `transform:rotate()` to create areas with diagonal borders - which seemed to work great in the beginning - but when scrolling down, the content in the duplicated areas moves further to the left, the further you scroll. In the lower areas it even starts too far right. None of this happens when I'm not rotating the containers. 
Any idea why that happens and what to do to fix this?

Comment: Avoid using external links as this question will essentially become invalid if that link's content moves or changes. Additionally, a jsFiddle replicating the problem on a smaller scale will be helpful.